# $\frac{a^3}{b^2}+\frac{b^3}{c^2}+\frac{c^3}{a^2}\geq a^2+b^2+c^2$

Tags: inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Let $a,b$ and $c$ be positive reals such that $a+b+c=3$. Prove that
$$\frac{a^3}{b^2}+\frac{b^3}{c^2}+\frac{c^3}{a^2}\geq a^2+b^2+c^2 $$

Attempt : Homogenizing the equation by letting $a=\frac{3x}{x+y+z}, b=\frac{3y}{x+y+z}$ and $c=\frac{3z}{x+y+z}$, the inequality becomes 
$$\frac{x^3}{y^2}+\frac{y^3}{z^2}+\frac{z^3}{x^2}\geq \frac{3\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)}{x+y+z}$$ where $x,y,z >0$. I am stuck here. Just a hint would suffice.(No calculus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $c=\min\{a,b,c\}$.

Hence, we need to prove that
$$\frac{a^3}{b^2}+\frac{b^3}{c^2}+\frac{c^3}{a^2}\geq\frac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{a+b+c}$$ or
$$\frac{a^3}{b^2}+\frac{b^3}{a^2}-a-b+\frac{b^3}{c^2}+\frac{c^3}{a^2}-\frac{b^3}{a^2}-c\geq\frac{3(a^2+b^2+c^2)}{a+b+c}-a-b-c$$ or
$$\frac{(a-b)^2(a+b)(a^2+ab+b^2)}{a^2b^2}+\frac{(c-a)(c-b)(a+c)(b^2+bc+c^2)}{a^2c^2}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{2(a-b)^2}{a+b+c}+\frac{2(c-a)(c-b)}{a+b+c},$$
which is obvious.

Done!

Comment: can you explain a bit how did you get there ? I mean the thought process.

Comment: @user244821 I don't understand your question. I am ready to explain my solution.

Comment: Is there some intuition behind introducing those various terms in the second line of your solution or it just struck you ?

Comment: @user244821 I just knew that all cyclic inequality of three variables $a$, $b$ and $c$ we can write in the form: $M(a-b)^2+N(c-a)(c-b)\geq0$. I made it and quit proof. I was just lucky.

Comment: Oh, i see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution: Assume $x\geq y\geq z>0$
$$\frac{x^3}{y^2}+\frac{y^3}{z^2}+\frac{z^3}{x^2}\geq \frac{3\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)}{x+y+z}$$ or
$$\left(\frac{x^4}{y^2}+\frac{y^4}{z^2}+\frac{z^4}{x^2}\right)+\left(\frac{xy^3}{z^2}+\frac{x^3}{y}\right)+\left(\frac{yz^3}{x^2}+\frac{y^3}{z}\right)+\left(\frac{zx^3}{y^2}+\frac{z^3}{x}\right)\geq 3\left(x^2+y^2+z^2\right)$$ Now
$$\frac{x^4}{y^2}+\frac{y^4}{z^2}+\frac{z^4}{x^2}\geq x^2+y^2+z^2\,\,\,\text{(Cauchy–Schwarz)}$$
and 
$$\left(\frac{xy^3}{z^2}+\frac{x^3}{y}\right)+\left(\frac{yz^3}{x^2}+\frac{y^3}{z}\right)+\left(\frac{zx^3}{y^2}+\frac{z^3}{x}\right)\geq \frac{2x^2y}{z}+\frac{2y^2z}{x}+\frac{2z^2x}{y}\,\text{(AM-GM)}$$
So, it is enough to prove that 
$$\frac{x^2y}{z}+\frac{y^2z}{x}+\frac{z^2x}{y}\geq x^2+y^2+z^2$$ which after simplifying becomes 
$$y(x-z)(y-z)(x^2+zx-zy)+z^3(x-y)^2\geq 0$$ which follows from the assumption.

Comment: You can assume $x\geq y\geq z>0$ only for symmetric expressions. Here, the expression is not symmetric but cyclic, hence you must examine two cases separately, $x\geq y\geq z>0$ and $y\geq x\geq z>0$. The two can be combine by assuming that $x$ and $y$ are no smaller than $z$.